# AJAX success can't populate data to table HTML

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I use ajax to filter data on the table. But when success call, data didn't show on the table. Data on the table disappear.

This my script code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inputJenis").change(function() {
        var key = $(this).val();
        var jenis_semester = 'key=' + key;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo base_url("search/filter") ?>',
            data: jenis_semester,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('table tbody').html(data);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my controller :

```
public function filter()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $key = $this->input->post('key');

        if ( $key == 'Ganjil' ) {
            $this->load->model('filter_model', 'filter');
            $data['semester'] = $this->filter->getGanjil($key);
        } else {
            $this->load->model('filter_model', 'filter');
            $data['semester'] = $this->filter->getGenap($key);
        }
        $this->load->view('tambah_semester', $data);

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

This is my model :

```
public function getGanjil($key)
    {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tahunajaran WHERE jenis = 'Ganjil'";
        $data = $this->db->query($sql);
        $index = 1;
        foreach ($data->result() as $row) {
            $dataSemester[$index] = array('id_tahun_ajaran' =>$row->id_tahun_ajaran,
                            'awal_semester' =>$row->awal_semester ,
                            'akhir_semester'=> $row->akhir_semester,
                            'tahun_ajaran'=>$row->tahun_ajaran,
                            'jenis'=>$row->jenis,
                            'nama_semester'=>$row->nama_semester );
            $index++;
        }
        return $dataSemester;
    }

    public function getGenap($key)
    {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tahunajaran WHERE jenis = 'Genap'";
        $data = $this->db->query($sql);
        $index = 1;
        foreach ($data->result() as $row) {
            $dataSemester[$index] = array('id_tahun_ajaran' =>$row->id_tahun_ajaran,
                            'awal_semester' =>$row->awal_semester ,
                            'akhir_semester'=> $row->akhir_semester,
                            'tahun_ajaran'=>$row->tahun_ajaran,
                            'jenis'=>$row->jenis,
                            'nama_semester'=>$row->nama_semester );
            $index++;
        }
        return $dataSemester;
    }
```

I want to show data on the table HTML

```
<table class="footable table table-striped" data-page-size="10">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td id="colNomer">Id</td>
            <td id="colNama">Nama</td>
            <td id="colTanggal">Awal semester</td>
            <td id="colTanggal">Akhir semester</td>
            <td id="colTanggal">Tahun ajaran</td>
            <td id="colNama">Jenis</td>
            <td id="colAksi">Aksi</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

May we fill table on the success call ajax. This is the pict 
[image]
the data can't populate on the table

[image]

Comment: in your model function `getGanjil()` where is the `$key` being used?

Answer (score 2):

I would separate your controller methods, one for AJAX call, the other for your normal view like so:

```
public function doFilter($key) {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('filter_model', 'filter');
    if ($key == 'Ganjil') {
        $data['semester'] = $this->filter->getGanjil($key);
    } else {
        $data['semester'] = $this->filter->getGenap($key);
    }
    return $data;
}

public function getFilterJson() {
    $key = $this->input->post('key');
    $data = $this->doFilter($key);
    echo json_encode($data);
}

public function filter() {
    $key = $this->input->post('key');
    $data = $this->doFilter($key);
    $this->load->view('tambah_semester', $data);
}
```

you also need to pass an object to your AJAX call and add the new URL we created in the controller, I would also use jquery's `$.post()` , so change your JS like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inputJenis").change(function() {
        $('table tbody').empty();//this will make sure the table is empty first
        var key = $(this).val();
        var postdata = {key: key};
        var url = '<?php echo base_url("search/getFilterJson") ?>';
        $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (result) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                $.each(obj, function(key, line) {
                    var elem = '<tr>\n\
                                    <td>' + line.id + '</td>\n\
                                    <td>' + line.Nama + '</td>\n\
                                    <td>' + line.Awal + '</td>\n\
                                    <td>' + line.Akhir + '</td>\n\
                                    <td>' + line.Tahun + '</td>\n\
                                    <td>' + line.Jenis + '</td>\n\
                                    <td>' + line.Aksi + '</td>\n\
                                </tr>';
                    $('table tbody').append(elem);
                 });
            } else {
                //your error code
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And your model, has too much going on. You should use Codeigniter's functions, like this:

```
public function getGanjil($key) {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("tahunajaran");
    $this->db->where("jenis", "Ganjil");
    $data = $this->db->get();
    return $data->result_array();
}

public function getGenap($key) {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("tahunajaran");
    $this->db->where("jenis", "Genap");
    $data = $this->db->get();
    return $data->result_array();
}
```

Comment: in your `ajax` `success` method, can you `console(data)` and let me know what results you get?

Comment: in your model, what is the `$key` variable for? i dont see it being used.

Comment: nothing's happen bro. I want to filter data on the table, when user choose value from select box, example 'Ganjil' then data on the table change just show data that have row 'Ganjil'

Comment: ok, in the JS I provided, when you `console.log(key)` after `var key = $(this).val();` what do you get?

Comment: do you know how to use the `console`?

Comment: No problem, we all start like that. Ok, if you are using chrome, press `F12`, then click the `console` tab. Now when you reload your page you should see the results of your `console.log()` here. Let me know what you get

Comment: your AJAX work bro, but what i want is table just show data that have row 'Ganjil' or 'Genap' when user choose value from select box. In your code, table add new data not filter it. any idea ?

Comment: im a little confused in what youre saying. I added a line that will empty the table when you change it.. but, in my AJAX, what are you receiving? can you `console.log(results)` and see the results in json format?

Comment: i got this error in console

GET http://localhost/BK/asset/img/nav-expand.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost/BK/asset/css/bootstrap.css.map 404 (Not Found)

Comment: The data added continue if i change the select box. What's wrong ?

Comment: that means that youre trying to load an image `nav-expand.png`, but its failing, the same for `bootstrap.css.map`.. thats not our concern right now.. do you see anything else? we are looking to see if your JSON is returned.

Comment: what do you mean by "the data added continue" ?

Comment: do you have Teamviwer? maybe i can log in and help you remotely

Comment: i mean when we choose value from select box , data continue added on the table, can't filtered.

Comment: i fixed my problem sir. may i ask you sir ?
may we create html button in AJAX success call ? i mean inside <td> we create <button class=""></button> ???

Comment: hi im glad you were able to figure it out. and yes you can call that button but if you are planning on it having an event, you would have to bind that event after you append it to the DOM.. or give it an `onclick` attribute with the function you want it to perform